# Forming a dynamic SQL statement using query string parameters in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to dynamically create an MS SQL query based on query string parameters.

I'm currently using variables that request the values of any valid query string parameters: if the parameter isn't empty, then that variable forms part of the SQL statement. If it is empty, the variable remains blank.

For example:

```
 var search = Request["search"].IsEmpty() ? "" : Request["search"];
 var price = Request["price"].IsEmpty() ? "" : Request["price"];

 string searchSQL = "WHERE item_name LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
 string priceSQL = " AND item_price < " + price;

 string sql = "SELECT * from Items " + searchSQL + priceSQL;
```

If both query parameters are valid, then this sql query runs okay. But if the search parameter is empty and the price isn't, the sql query then becomes invalid:

```
SELECT * from Items AND item_price < 100
```

My plan is to use upto 6 different query string parameters, so this snippet of code can't really be used. What are the best practices for this type of method? Is it possible to create valid, dynamic sql statements this way?

Comment: Best practices starts with using parameters at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `null` parameters:

```
select *
from items
where (@name is null or item_name like '%' + @name + '%')
  and (@price is null or item_price < @price)";
```

Then you would add the parameters, and specify a `null` value for those that haven't been given, this will make that part of the WHERE statement not filter anything, and you don't have to build up a different SQL every time.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)'s approach is what I tend to use, although I've got one application where I use dynamic SQL to generate a more efficient query based on what the user wants to do (i.e., less joins when I can get away with it) . If you really have your heart set on dynamic SQL, you can use the ternary operator to make a better query:

```
string search = Request("search").IsEmpty() ? "" : Request("search");
decimal price = Request("price").IsEmpty() ? "" : Request("price");
string param3 = Request("param3").IsEmpty() ? "" : Request("param3");
string param4 = Request("param4").IsEmpty() ? "" : Request("param4");
string param5 = Request("param5").IsEmpty() ? "" : Request("param5");
string param6 = Request("param6").IsEmpty() ? "" : Request("param6");

string whereClause = "";

whereClause += whereClause.length > 0 & search.length > 0 ? " AND item_name LIKE '%' + @search + '%'" : "WHERE item_name LIKE '%' + @search + '%'";
whereClause += whereClause.length > 0 & search.length > 0 ? " AND item_price < @price" : "WHERE item_price < @price";
whereClause += whereClause.length > 0 & search.length > 0 ? " AND param3 = @param3" : "WHERE param3 = @param3";
whereClause += whereClause.length > 0 & search.length > 0 ? " AND param4 = @param4" : "WHERE param4 = @param4";
whereClause += whereClause.length > 0 & search.length > 0 ? " AND param5 = @param5" : "WHERE param5 = @param5";
whereClause += whereClause.length > 0 & search.length > 0 ? " AND param6 = @param6" : "WHERE param6 = @param6";

string sql = "SELECT * from Items " + whereClause;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

// fill in all parameters (even ones that may not exist)
cmd.Parameters.Add("search", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = search;
cmd.Parameters.Add("price", SqlDbType.Float).Value = price;
cmd.Parameters.Add("param3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = param3;
cmd.Parameters.Add("param4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = param4;
cmd.Parameters.Add("param5", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = param5;
cmd.Parameters.Add("param6", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = param6;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, pete! Your answer is still helpful nonetheless,  I'll experiment with the two and see what works best in this instance!

Answer (score 0):

If you were to convert your application to use `Entity Framework` or `Linq2Sql` (or similar ORM framework). You would be able to build up a query in code, and then send it to the database.

Below is a code example using Entity Framework. In this example, following your example, we use the `DbSet<Item>` from the `DbContext`. It inherits `IQueryable<Item>`, which is also the return type from many extension methods, such as `Where`. We can now chain a series of where statements together, to create the query you want.

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
    IQueryable<Item> items = db.Items;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemName))
        items = items.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(itemName));

    if (maxPrice > 0)
        items = items.Where(s => s.Price < maxPrice);

    // Get results
    List<Item> results = items.ToList();
}
```

Note however, that the SQL generatede from this will be a tad more complex than `SELECT * from Items AND item_price < 100`, as it's up to the SQL Generator to create this.