# an error when choosing between two specific date in datagridview in VISUAL BASIC

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i wrote a code for **searching between two specific date in Visual Basic** and it was run correctly.

but now there's a *problem*.
- when i chose between two date in DECEMBER that i inserted a data in, it show correctly. 
-- *but* when i chose two date in month before that doesn't have any data ***it show the DECEMBER data.***
-- *also* when i chose a date in DECEMBER and the another in JANUARY ***there's no data!***

- i use MS Access for my data base - 
  here is my code...

```css
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.DataTable
Public Class p2
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sh\Desktop\FP\Fproject.accdb"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim Str As String
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader

    Private Sub p2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        MyConn.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Str = "SELECT * FROM att WHERE (date1 between '" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "' and '" & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString & "')"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Str, MyConn)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                ds = New DataSet
                tables = ds.Tables
                da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select id1 from [att] where (date1 >= '" & Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "' and date1 <= '" & Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString & "')", MyConn)
                da.Fill(ds, "att")
                Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
                source1.DataSource = view
                DataGridView1.DataSource = view
                Return
            End If
        End While

        MsgBox("no data for this chosen date", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Warning")
        DateTimePicker1.Value = Now
        Return
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        FirstForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider [using parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279197/forming-a-dynamic-sql-statement-using-query-string-parameters-in-asp-net) instead of concatenated strings.

Comment: @Paul would you please explain more

Comment: Maybe you should follow the link rather than expecting to be spoon fed.  If there's something there that you don't understand, ask about that specifically.

Comment: If you want dates to act like dates they have to be date types.  We dont know what type the column is in the database, but `DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString` is a string, not a date.

Comment: Apologies - Christmas period and all. One of the problems with using a concatenated string as opposed to [stored procedures or prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) is exactly the problem you're experiencing at the moment. If you search S.O [there are hundreds of examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+parameter+stored+procedure) of how to do exactly what you're after.